# Prevent the page scrolling down each time "page" button link are clicked?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I´m using scrollTo jQuery plugin on a wordpress page and wonder if 
there is a way to prevent the page scrolling down each time "page" button link are clicked?

http://www.missbee.se/missBeev1/?page_id=5#page1

Here is my code,

```
$(function() {

var $target = $('#mask');
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $target.scrollTo($('#page1'),500);
        });
        $('#btn2').click(function() {
        $target.scrollTo($('#page2'),500);
        });
        $('#btn3').click(function() {
        $target.scrollTo($('#page3'),500);
        });
        $('#btn4').click(function() {
        $target.scrollTo($('#page4'),500);
        });
        $('#btn5').click(function() {
        $target.scrollTo($('#page5'),500);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the page 'jumping' down is the fact that your links are actually navigating to the IDs used when clicked.

To remedy this, simply change each of your calls as follows:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $target.scrollTo($('#page1'),500);
});
```

The 'e' being passed into the anonymous function is the click event itself. e.preventDefault() does exactly what it says on the tin... Prevents the default action being fired - In this case navigating to the href specified on the link.

Incidentally you can condense your script down to one function rather than using a separate function for each link as follows:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $target.scrollTo($(href),500);
});
```

This one function can handle all of your links in one, as it fetches the target href from the link that is clicked, rather than having to write a separate function for each one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just as a side note, please don't ever add onclick='return false' to a link as suggested below. This is coding from the 90s and it should stay there - Keep markup and JS separate. Why would you introduce something functional like that into your document when there is no need to. e.preventDefault() does the same thing without polluting your html.

Comment: arttronics - please don't remove your answers after the fact just because someone suggests that they aren't the correct way of doing things. It makes the comments useless and removes a potentially valuable resource for future visitors. 

wpdesign - Would you please accept my answer if you are happy with it? My account is new here and I could do with the rep :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using jQuery UI tabs for the purpose you're trying to attain. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ for example and information.